# Unable to spinup orderers in Raft consensus in hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft

I am extending the first network example with raft consensus on multiple hosts. When I try to start the orderers, the first orderer starts up but, I can not start any other orderers from both the same organisation and other organisation. The error I get as follows

> [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 019 [channel:
>   orderersyschannel] Client authorization revoked for deliver request
>   from 172.18.0.5:45506:  implicit policy evaluation failed - 0
>   sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the
>   'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied 2019-09-23
>   07:22:52.937 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 01a streaming call
>   completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver
>   grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.5 :45506
>   grpc.peer_subject="CN=ord1-org2,OU=orderer,O=Hyperledger,ST=North
>   Carolina,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.590709ms
>   2019-09-23 07:22:52.945 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.replication]
>   fetchLastBlockSeq -> WARN 01b Received status:FORBIDDEN  from
>   ord1-org2.local:7050: forbidden pullin g the channel
>   2019-09-23 07:22:52.945 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.replication] func1
>   -> WARN 01c Received error of type 'forbidden pulling the channel' from {ord1-org2.local:7050

I also checked my policies in 'configtx.yaml'

In Organisations section:

```
              Readers:
                  Type: Signature
                  Rule: "OR('org2MSP.member', 'org2MSP.admin', 'org2MSP.peer', 'org2MSP.client')"
              Writers:
                  Type: Signature
                  Rule: "OR('org2MSP.member', 'org2MSP.admin', 'org2MSP.client')"
              Admins:
                  Type: Signature
                  Rule: "OR('org2MSP.admin')"
```

in Orderer section I have:

```
         Readers:
             Type: ImplicitMeta
             Rule: "ANY Readers"
         Writers:
             Type: ImplicitMeta
             Rule: "ANY Writers"
         Admins:
             Type: ImplicitMeta
             Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
         # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
         # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
         BlockValidation:
             Type: ImplicitMeta
             Rule: "ANY Writers"
```

I am not sure why the policies or not met. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: It seems you have not defined all the participating orgs in the system channel. Can you add your configtx.yaml file?

Comment: @Trinayan I have pasted my configtx.yaml here
https://pastebin.com/SLaGSrid

Comment: From Orderer2 of org1, I get the error: 
 [orderer.common.cluster.replication] fetchLastBlockSeq -> ERRO 030 Failed  receiving the latest block from ord1-org1.local:7050: didn't receive a  response within 7s [orderer.common.cluster.replication] func1 -> WARN 031 Received error of type 'didn't receive a response within 7s' from {ord1-org1.local:7050 [-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIICIjCCAcigAwIBAgIUbn1FGuhGesOdjUovQI+ERiV+2xUwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw 
I have also done the following recommendation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490469/why-deliverblocks-fail-with-policy-evaluation-error

Answer (score 0):

Try by editing this block in your configtx.yaml file and regenerate genesis block.

```
Profiles:
    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
               - *Org1
               **- *Org2**
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                   - *Org1
                    - *Org2
```

Comment: Thanks Trinayan, I am not using TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis profile. Now I managed to spin up the orderers but, can not create a channel :(. The CLI shows some logs and then waits forever.

Comment: Sure: the log during creating a channel: https://pastebin.com/ahEU6Fn9 
at the end of the log the shell does nothing, just waits

Comment: It seems your orderers are not able to communicate with each other. Check if diffrent hosts have the orderer ports open and if you can ping from one host to another.